# How to avoid session time out with ajax only

Tags: ajax, extjs, symfony, extjs4

I have an ext js 4 app with symfony 2 backend and session configuration like this:

```
framework:
  ... 
  session:
      default_locale: %locale%
      auto_start:     true
      lifetime: 1800
  ...
```

When using the app the session expires whenever the lifetime elapsed after login, even if request are sent to the server by ajax. 
I didnt find an solution how to avoid this. Or what am I getting wrong?

Comment: Duplicate of my question which has been answered. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8611247/how-can-i-refresh-the-session-during-a-post-request

Answer (score 0):

I doubt your problem is that your using ajax. Far as i know, ajax requests should be handled like any other SF request, and your session should be extended like normal.